# send QHTTP request with user agent added

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

send QHTTP request with user agent added

there is an example in C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\examples\network\http

but I want to add User-Agent header to the http request ,so I commented

```
##        self.httpGetId = self.http.get(path, self.outFile)
```

and write the following code

```
header = QtNetwork.QHttpRequestHeader("GET", path)#1
header.setValue("Host", url.host())
header.setValue('User-Agent' ,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.60 Safari/537.17')

self.http.setHost(url.host())
```

then here is the question ,I don’t know how to Send this request with the header added to the server?

P.S. 
I referred the documentation ,found perhaps

```
int QHttp::request ( const QHttpRequestHeader & header, QIODevice * data = 0, QIODevice * to = 0 )
```

would come to help me solve this question ,but I wonder what ‘data’ should be in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`QNetworkAcessManager`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) to send your request, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtNetwork

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    print "Starting request...",

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    url = QtCore.QUrl("http://www.example.com/")

    request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest()
    request.setUrl(url)
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyAppName/1.0 (Nokia; Qt)")

    manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
    manager.finished.connect(app.quit)
    manager.get(request)

    print "done."

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```